# Why does this converge to $1$ when $n \to \infty ?$

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory

This is what it says, I understand why this is for $t \leq 0$ and $\frac{1}{n}<t\leq 1$ but not the rest. Anyway:

$X_n$ are an array of independent ransom variables with the uniform distribution of $U((0,\frac{1}{n})\cup (1,1+\frac{1}{n^2}))$

$$F_{X_n}(t)=\begin{cases}0, t\leq 0 \\ \frac{t}{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}},0<t\leq \frac{1}{n} \\ \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}, \frac{1}{n}<t\leq 1 \\ \frac{t-1+\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}, 1<t\leq1+\frac{1}{n^2}\\ 1, t>1+\frac{1}{n^2} \end{cases}\\ \to_{n\to \infty} \begin{cases}0,t\leq0\\ 1, t>0 \end{cases}$$

How?

Comment: Do you know what $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}$ is?

Comment: 1 is the limit of what you ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $0<t\le 1$ then for $n$ large enough, $\frac1n<t$ and hence $F_{X_n}(t)=\frac{\frac1n}{\frac1n+\frac1{n^2}}=\frac{1}{1+\frac1n}\to 1$.

If $t>1$ then for sufficiently large $n$, $t>1+\frac1{n^2}$ and hence $F_{X_n}(t)=1$ for such $n$.

Note that it doesn't even matter how $F_{X_n}(t)$ is defined for $0<t\le \frac1n$ or for $1<t\le 1+\frac1{n^2}$. The function could be arbitrarily wild or discontinuous and unbounded as much as it likes there.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You already understand $t\leq0$, so suppose $1\geq t>0$. Then $t>1/n$ for all sufficiently large $n$. A similar argument holds for $t>1$.